# How to use the Field API and Field attribute in django

Tags: django, django-models

How to use the Field API like

```
get_internal_type()
get_prep_value(value)
from_db_value(value, expression, connection)
```

and get the value from Field attributes like

```
Field.auto_created
Field.concrete
Field.is_relation
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. What is the use case? What variables do you have, what do you want to obtain?

Comment: how to set Field.auto_created and get the value from it..
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#field-attribute-reference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#field-api-reference